# $_POST and variable indexes

Tags: php, html, post

I have a project where I create hidden input values with jQuery. These represent groups and members so I have one array for the groups themselves and arrays with the members of each groups.

For example after a few creations the code in the form includes

```
<input type="hidden" name="groups['group_2']" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="groups['group_1']" value="0">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1[]" value="FWNGVISkjW">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1[]" value="G0t9E3C0yG">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_2[]" value="NT-JEDVCS9">
```

for an example of 2 groups with 2 members in group_1 and 1 member in group_2.

Now, after the submit my code to iterate through the values I use this code:

```
if ($groups_no && isset($_POST['groups']) && !empty($_POST['groups'])){
    $groups = $_POST['groups'];
    foreach ($groups as $key => $val){
        if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key])){
            $group_members = $_POST[$key];      
            foreach ($group_members as $member_key => $member_val){
                echo 'Actions to be done here!';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I get the following warning and the program fails:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 'group_1' in C:\ ... .php on line 31
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...
Notice: Undefined index: 'group_2' in C:\ ... .php on line 31
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ...
```

When I use `$_POST['group_1']` everything works fine but since I do not know how many and which groups I will have to insert I need the variable. I have tried some different things suggested via some Google results but nothing worked.

Any ideas? Is `$_POST` even capable of having variables as indexes? Also if it isn't, is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, don't put quotes around the array indexes.

```
<input type="hidden" name="groups[group_2]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="groups[group_1]" value="0">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1[]" value="FWNGVISkjW">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1[]" value="G0t9E3C0yG">
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_2[]" value="NT-JEDVCS9">
```

Comment: Ye that was it! Thank you very much for the quick reply and solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

By doing this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1[]" value="FWNGVISkjW">
```

Instead of this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="mem_id_holder" name="group_1" value="FWNGVISkjW">
```

When you post the values you are going to get an array, so `$_POST['group_1']` would not exist as a string in the first instance, it would be `$_POST['group_1'][0]`. So you would have to iterate through that value as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: He is iterating through both arrays.